# struts2 nest text tag with property tag in jsp

Tags: java, jsp, jakarta-ee, struts2

I have been researching this online for a long while with no luck so I decide to ask.

In my application, the action class generates a value, which I can display through the

```
s:property
```

tag without a problem.  However, since that string also has to be translated to other languages, I want to use that property value as the key for the

```
s:text
```

tag.

Obviously,

```
<s:text name="<s:property value="variable"/>"/>
```

doesn't work.

How can I do this without first translating it in the action class?  I can do this within the java action class, but I want this to be done in the jsp because I want to preserve the variable. It has some signifance in some other javascript function.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

it is very easy. If your action class extends `ActionSupport`, you can always do this in your jsp file.

```
<s:property value="getText('your.key')"/>
```

`your.key` should be saved in your struts2 language.properties file

**EDIT**

If you are using a dynamic string, you should replace `your.key` with an action property.

```
<s:property value="getText(yourProperty)"/>
```

Comment: Except that the question was regarding a dynamic `your.key`, not an immediate string. Replace `your.key` with an action property value containing the key, and this is correct.